# Rest with Android 4.0

Tags: android, rest

Folks, I have an web service running on my PC, recently I changed my application from 2.2. for 4.0, and after that I cant connect to my WS anymore.

I'm looking for answers and found nothing.

My application refers the URL like this`http://10.0.2.2:8080`  ... But it dosn't work.

Heres my code:

```
private static final String URL_WS = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WS_TaxiShare/)";


public String login(String email, String password) throws Exception {

    String[] resposta = new WSClient().get(URL_WS + "login/login/?login="+ email +"&password="+ password);

    String saida = resposta[1];
    if (resposta[0].equals("200")) {
        return saida;
    } else {
        return saida;
    }
}
```

Now the WSClient

```
public class WSClient {

    public final String[] get(String url) {

        String[] result = new String[2];
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response;

        try {
        Log.i("Get taxi", "Url -> " + url);
        response = HttpClientSingleton.getHttpClientInstace().execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result[1] = toString(instream);
            instream.close();
            Log.i("get", "Result from post JsonPost : " + result[0] + " : " + result[1]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Exception no get WS taxi", "Exception ->" + e);
        result[0] = "0";
        result[1] = "Falha de rede!";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i can solve my problem. Android 4.0 (I dont know when it begin), you cant call webservices on the main thread. And all you need to do is create a async method to do what you need in a separeated thread.

Here is my method

```
private class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String response = "";


    try {


        WSTaxiShare ws = new WSTaxiShare();

        response = ws.login(login, password);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {



}
```

and here is the call button

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        loginTask task = new loginTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "" });

    }
});
```

}